# How to implement scrolling in a RichTextBlock in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Phone Universal app that has a `RichTextBlock` which loads its content dynamically. Sometimes the content is short and sometimes its too long to fit in a page; hence, I would like the `RichTextBlock` to expand dynamically and give the user the ability to scroll to see the entire content.

I looked around (here and other places) for piece of code that achieves this, but was not very successful. The closest I got was the following code that **doesn't work**:

```
<ScrollViewer Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <RichTextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="White" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False" Margin="12,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Paragraph>
            Place a very long text here.
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `RichTextBlock` should not have a `Margin` and please fix the `Height` of `ScrollViewer` to some constant value and try. Also, make sure that `RichTextBlock` can virtually extend beyond the bounds of its parent. Only then, putting it inside `ScrollViewer` makes sense.

Comment: Why shouldn't the `RichTextBlock` have `Margin`?

Comment: If `RichTextBlock` has a margin, it means that it is confined to certain bounds on the screen. ScrollViewer is useful only if the `RichTextBlock` margin goes out of screen. Only then, you will get scrolling action enabled.

Comment: Yes, `ScrollViewer` is useful when its child content goes off the screen, and this has nothing to do with the child margins. Margins are relative to the parent/container not the screen; hence, `RichTextBlock` margins in my example are the distance from `ScrollViewer` `ContentPresenter` edges and not `ScrollViewer` itself. In other words, `RichTextBlock` will continue to expand when it has more content (its `Height` is `Auto`) and will maintain its margins to the `ContentPresenter`, which expands as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="150" Width="150">
    <RichTextBlock>
        <Paragraph>This is my RichTextblock</Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The trick here is to fix the `Height` and/or `Width` (depending on which direction you want to scroll).

Back to the example in the question; all it needs is an absolute value; e.g., `Height="480"`:

```
<ScrollViewer Width="Auto" Height="480" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <RichTextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="White" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False" Margin="12,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Paragraph>
            Place a very long text here.
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```